# What does it mean a ! before the username field in /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, rhel, users, password

After doing some googling I could not find why in the `/etc/passwd`

shows a `!` at the beginning of the line.

It looks like this:

```
!user:x:0:0:user:/home/user:/bin/bash
```

any ideas? my only guess is that perhaps the user no longer exist.

Comment: How do you login as root ?

Comment: @don_crissti is not the only user. obviously not with that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This essentially does nothing more than changing the username to `!user`, so if you try to login as `user` you will get:

```
No passwd entry for user 'user'
```

as the username has been changed to `!user`.

Now if you change the `/etc/shadow` too and set the username as `!user`, then you can login as the user `!user` using the same password used for `user`.

If you want to block a user from logging in using password, you should add a `!` to the password field of `/etc/shadow` or better use `passwd -l` command.

Comment: @user2171775 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd) :

> "!" – the account is password locked, user will be unable to log-in
>   via password authentication but other methods (e.g. ssh key) may be
>   still allowed)[7]

In addition, it also seems that the significance of `!` in `/etc/passwd` can vary depending on the position(colon) which it is. [At this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.security/passwords_etc_passwd_file.htm) they provide an example of entries where the `!` is located in the password field, like this :

```
root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/ksh
daemon:!:1:1::/etc:
bin:!:2:2::/bin:
```

and they explain that

> If a user ID has a password, then the password field will have an !
>   (exclamation point).

Comment: well I went to the wikipedia and that information applies to the /etc/shadow not the /etc/passwd

Comment: The OP isn't asking about a '!' in the password field, that's well documented.  They're asking about the '!' at the beginning of the line.

Comment: if it isn't useful can be removed, heemayl provided a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the entry still exists in the `/etc/passwd` file means the user still exists.  Placing a '!' at the beginning of the line is, as far as I know, not a standard procedure but it would have the effect of disabling logins for that user.